# emulating phpMyAdmin Export function

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export

When you export a database from phpMyAdmin, it returns an SQL file with create table queries and all the table data and information currently stored.

I want to create a button that downloads this to a file for the user.

is this possible, if so how?

Comment: As in, you want to give users access to export your full database - but without access to phpmyadmin? If so, check out the command-line tool `mysqldump` with PHP's `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

You use a mime type header that will suggest the user downloads the file and output the "created on the fly" sql insert codes that will create the entire table.

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
```

You can should be able to use [PDO's get column meta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) to get the column types for your initial make table SQL.

The output looks like this:

```
<?php
$select = $DB->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit');
$meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
var_dump($meta);
?>

array(6) {
  ["native_type"]=>
  string(7) "integer"
  ["flags"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "COUNT(*)"
  ["len"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["precision"]=>
  int(0)
  ["pdo_type"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Then you query the database and use the data that is returned to generate an insert statement for each row that is returned from your initial query.

Comment: or just use mysqldumpand don't reinvent the wheel ;)